# Heroku Procfile won't run Django app

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to fire up my Django app locally using my Heroku Procfile. But it errors out with the following message:

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8313] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8313] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (8313)
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8313] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8317] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8317
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8317] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
web.1  | til.py", line 355, in import_app
web.1  | ortlandpython/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8317] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8317)
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8313] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web.1  | [2015-12-23 13:27:19 -0800] [8313] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.config.settings.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

My wsgi file is located at mysite/config/settings/wsgi.py

Is there a fix here?

Comment: Did you try just `web: gunicorn mysite.config.settings.wsgi` or `web: gunicorn mysite.config.settings.wsgi:application`? Also, what do you mean by "Deploying Locally using Heroku Procfile? Are you attempting to use the same settings locally that you are using in production?

Comment: `web: gunicorn mysite.config.settings.wsgi` got me running. Basically, I wanted to be able to run Django management commands using the a command like `heroku local:run python manage.py runserver --settings=config.settings.local` Feel free to add a solution and I'll accept.

Comment: Glad to hear! I posted it as the answer in case anyone else stumbles in and needs a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.config.settings.wsgi
```